# Decrypt String AES 256 outside of Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, encryption

I'm using framework laravel for encryption some string, in my laravel i write the code like this :

```
public function getBankNameAttribute(){
    return Crypt::encrypt($this->attributes['bank_name']);
}
```

The result is String 'abc' encrypted to String

> 'eyJpdiI6InBxeTlKOVdFQ1FoN2hGNDdPSTJZUnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVzlQYVpsSlptUHF6QUMwalM0c21vZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNGFlYmY3OTk2MDUyYTcwMzMxMGYzYmQzODRhODUyNWRlZjMzNjNmMDU5NTJiMDg2NmJjNzhkYjI5NTkzYzI1YSJ9'

The return of the encrypt is always different because of generate IV from laravel.If the output is always different,how can i decrypt the string outside laravel. Especially for Android.

I have searching the whole documentation on Google, but no one made it for Android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Probabl this can help](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/11/01/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-java/).

Comment: Look for into the source and recreate it for Java.

Comment: I'm confusing at $value = openssl_encrypt($value, $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);

how to openssl_decrypt in android, I want a simple way..

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The link in the comment by TheAlpha should be enough. I'll just add that if you Base64 decode the string 'eyJpdiI6InBxeTlKOVdFQ1FoN2hGNDdPSTJZUnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVzlQYVpsSlptUHF6QUMwalM0c21vZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNGFlYmY3OTk2MDUyYTcwMzMxMGYzYmQzODRhODUyNWRlZjMzNjNmMDU5NTJiMDg2NmJjNzhkYjI5NTkzYzI1YSJ9' (for instance using https://www.base64decode.org/) you will get a JSON file with three values:

- iv: Initial Vector - used to generate randomness when encrypting - needed to decrypt
- value: the value that you actually want to decrypt - you need the iv and the secret key used to encrypt to actually decrypt it
- mac: you can use to check that the value has not been tampered with.
  This optional but recommended.

See also: [How to decrypt in Java (Android) text that was encrypted with Crypt in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975822/how-to-decrypt-in-java-android-text-that-was-encrypted-with-crypt-in-laravel)