# How to decrypt in Java (Android) text that was encrypted with Crypt in Laravel?

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, cryptography

I need to decrypt some data that I receive from the server, and the programmer who made the API directed me to this [Encrypter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php) class, to see what he used to encrypt.

Now based on that class, I found that the algorithm used is AES128 CBC, and that the string I receive is Base64 encoded and contains other data, not just the ciphertext.

Namely that if I receive the following String:

```
eyJpdiI6InJsSzRlU3pDZTBBUVNwMzdXMjVcL0tBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ik5JOENsSVVWaWk2RGNhNlwvWjJNeG94UzVkclwvMGJOREQreWUyS1UzclRMND0iLCJtYWMiOiJhZTZkYjNkNGM2ZTliNmU0ZTc0MTRiNDBmMzFlZTJhNTczZWIxMjk4N2YwMjlhODA1NTIyMDEzODljNDY2OTk2In0
```

after base64 decoding I get:

```
{"iv":"rlK4eSzCe0AQSp37W25\/KA==","value":"NI8ClIUVii6Dca6\/Z2MxoxS5dr\/0bNDD+ye2KU3rTL4=","mac":"ae6db3d4c6e9b6e4e7414b40f31ee2a573eb12987f029a80552201389c466996"}
```

Based on `line 99` of `Encrypter` class ( `iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);` ), I performed another base64 decode on the `iv` and the `value` , and got an `iv` of length 16. Those I passed as parameters to the function below:

```
    public static String decrypt(String iv, String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyValue = "zy2dEd1pKG5i3WuWbvOBolFQR84AYbvN".getBytes();
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");        
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes()));
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    return new String(decValue);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 16
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineInitInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:281)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineInit(OpenSSLCipher.java:323)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:751)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:701)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.example.kushtrim.testproject.MainActivity.decrypt(MainActivity.java:62)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.example.kushtrim.testproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-06 19:13:33.601 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-06 19:13:33.602 12895-12895/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Note:** The String `iv` has length of 16, but `iv.getBytes()` returns an array of length 26.

Could someone point me to where I went wrong, and how do I fix it.
Thanks/

**EDIT**
After the comment, I made some changes, that resolved the above error:
Before I was base64 decoding `iv`, converting the bytes to String, then passing that String to the decrypt method, which in return called the getBytes() on it. Somehow this made the byte array have a length of 26.
Sending the byte array I obtained after base64 decoding to the decrypt method fixed the problem.
Now the method is as follows:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] iv, String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyValue = "zy2dEd1pKG5i3WuWbvOBolFQR84AYbvN".getBytes();
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    return new String(decValue);
}
```

Now I have another *weird* problem:
The text I encrypted on the first place was `KushtrimPacaj` , but the decrypted text is  `s:13:"KushtrimPacaj";` .
Where is that other part coming from ? 13 perhaps represents the length of `KushtrimPacaj` ?

**Edit**
Here's the working code, in case anyone needs it :
https://gist.github.com/KushtrimPacaj/43a383ab419fc222f80e

Comment: Please provide a full example. If `iv` is a String, what's its value? Have you forgot to decode it? I see no reason the length would be 26. Keep in mind that you cannot pass binary/unprintable data as a String. You would need to use a byte array.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the comment, you gave me an idea that led to the length problem. Though now I have another weird one ( see the edited question ). Any idea on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the [`padAndMcrypt()` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L79), that the given $value is serialized using PHP's [`serialize()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can [re-implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743402/unserialize-in-java-a-serialized-php-object) the `unserialize()` function in Java or you can split the byte array yourself if you're always encrypting strings in PHP.

```
int firstQuoteIndex = 0;
while(decValue[firstQuoteIndex] != (byte)'"') firstQuoteIndex++;
return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(decValue, firstQuoteIndex + 1, decValue.length-2));
```

Full code:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] keyValue, String ivValue, String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
    byte[] iv = Base64.decode(ivValue.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"); // or PKCS5Padding
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);

    int firstQuoteIndex = 0;
    while(decValue[firstQuoteIndex] != (byte)'"') firstQuoteIndex++;
    return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(decValue, firstQuoteIndex + 1, decValue.length-2));
}
```

Verifying the MAC is always a good idea, because it prevents some attacks such as the padding oracle attack. It is also a very good way to detect general modifications of ciphertexts.

Full code with MAC verification:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] keyValue, String ivValue, String encryptedData, String macValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
    byte[] iv = Base64.decode(ivValue.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);

    SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "HmacSHA256");
    Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    hmacSha256.init(macKey);
    hmacSha256.update(ivValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] calcMac = hmacSha256.doFinal(encryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] mac = Hex.decodeHex(macValue.toCharArray());
    if (!secureEquals(calcMac, mac))
        return null; // or throw exception

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"); // or PKCS5Padding
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue);

    int firstQuoteIndex = 0;
    while(decValue[firstQuoteIndex] != (byte)'"') firstQuoteIndex++;
    return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(decValue, firstQuoteIndex + 1, decValue.length-2));
}

/* Constant-time compare to prevent timing attacks on invalid authentication tags. */
public static boolean secureEquals(final byte[] known, final byte[] user) {
    int knownLen = known.length;
    int userLen = user.length;

    int result = knownLen ^ userLen;
    for (int i = 0; i < knownLen; i++) {
        result |= known[i] ^ user[i % userLen];
    }
    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I knew how to split the String but didn't dare to, because I didn't know why it was happening, and whether it would always follow the same pattern. Also could you edit the answer, and make the second parameter in copyOfRange : "firstQuoteIndex + 1", since the start index is inclusive. Stackoverflow won't let me make an edit that it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: I've added MAC verification. Can you check whether it works as expected?

Comment: `// TODO: use time-constant compare` Would you rather make a Github project for this?

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Not at this time, because ... I don't have the time to do this properly.

Comment: Yeah, it works as expected, with one minor change: I had to pass keyValue as first parameter to SecretKeySpec. Thanks :). Could you also check the MAC generation in the encrypt method ? I used the same IV, plaintext and key, but the MAC generated isn't the same that I received on the first place !

Comment: @Kushtrim The initial question is concerned with decryption which is already answered. I have no intention of blowing up the answer further. I would suggest that you ask a new question, but here are things to consider: (1) the IV has to be randomly generated and only encoded to Base64 after it was used for encryption and MAC. (2) There is probably some difference between the byte array length and String length when you do `plaintext.length()`.

Comment: https://github.com/reza-khalafi/LaravelCrypt/blob/master/laravelEncrypt.php

Comment: Everybody knows how to implement this code for Objective C?

Comment: @reza_khalafi If you have a new question, then do so. Comments of an unrelated Q&A are not the right place to ask for that.

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542851/how-to-implement-laravel-function-cryptencrypt-in-objective-c     @ArtjomB.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you please send the java encryption method, as I can find here decrypt but not able to find encrypt. Tried this one https://gist.github.com/KushtrimPacaj/43a383ab419fc222f80e but not working.

Comment: @VijaySankhat OK, the salary is 10000 €. You can send me 5000 € first and the second half upon completion of the contract work.